# babel exporting undefined when importing something

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

When importing something all exports are exporting undefined when generated.

Like this:

```
import something from '';

export const word1 = 'Hello';
export const word2 = 'World';
```

Will generate this:

```
exports.word2 = exports.word1 = undefined;
```

[I can reproduce it on babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZwiApjAFsAdgczgMymTgHISBuAKEpQA9JY4BjCLBeAd2gBMBGOALykAEigA2YiBRr1o8Fm048ATINIB1aGO7SgA&debug=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0)

Anyone that can tell me how I can fix this?

Maybe there is some plugin? or I should change the code?

Comment: Did you see the last two lines? It sets the values of `Hello` and `World` accordingly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on the link you provided. It looks completely different. The last two auto-generated lines are the following:
`
var word1 = exports.word1 = 'Hello';
var word2 = exports.word2 = 'World';
`

Comment: Ah, sorry. It works fine. It's just Webstorm that can't resolve it.

Comment: I reported it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29901

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this statement does is to create the properties on the `exports` object. This happens before the imported modules are `require`d - it's basically making the "hoisting" of the variables explicit.

The exported properties are then initialised later in the code.